# Real and imaginary part of an holomorphic function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, real-analysis, integration

I guess this could be a very elementary question. Anyway I can not find an answer in literature.

Let $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be an holomorphic function on an upen subset $U\subseteq\mathbb{C}$. Let us write $f(z) = u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, where $z = x+iy$.

Is there a way of proving that $u,v\in C^{1}(U)$ without using complex integrals, and in particular without using the Cauchy integral formula?

Here holomorphic in $U$ means holomorphic in any $z_0\in U$ that is for any point $z_0\in U$ there exists the limit
$$f^{'}(z) = \lim_{z\mapsto z_0}\frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}.$$

Comment: This has probably been addressed before on MathOverflow, but can you get what you want from the theory of "elliptic regularity"?

Comment: "Without using integrals" is a very strong requirement.

Comment: What is your definition of "holomorphic function"?

Comment: @YemonChoi Then it boils down to how to prove elliptic regularity without integrals.

Comment: Can you define precisely what you mean by holomorphic function?  Depending on the definition you use, the  question may have an immediate answer.

Comment: I added the definition.

Comment: Notice he assumes $f$ is (complex) differentiable, but not that $f$ is $C^1$.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the Dirichlet problem for Laplace's equation on a square by separation of variables and Fourier series. You can check explicitly from the Fourier series that the solution is $C^\infty$ inside the square. Now use the maximum principle to infer uniqueness.

Comment: But how can we make sense of the Laplace equation without assuming $C^1$ regularity? In the weak sense? But that is integration, again!